# What is wrong with converting jsp to thmeleaf?

Tags: jsp, thymeleaf

I'm going to change the technology that I've been paging with the existing jsp grammar to the thymeleaf grammar.

This is an existing jsp grammar.

```
 <c:forEach begin="0" end="${pageList.totalPages-1}" var="i">
   <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${pageList.number==i}">
         <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/board/list?nowPage=${i}" style="color:red"> [ ${i+1} ] </a>
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
         <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/board/list?nowPage=${i}"> [ ${i+1} ] </a>
     </c:otherwise>
   </c:choose>
   
 </c:forEach>
```

This is the thymeleaf grammar that I changed.

```
<div th:if="${pageList.content != null}">
    <span th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, pageList.totalPages-1)}">
        <span th:if="${pageList.number} == i">
            <a th:href="@{/testCase/projectList?(currentPage=${i})}" style="color: red">[[${i+1}]]</a>
        </span>
        <span th:unless="${pageList.number} == i">
            <a th:href="@{/testCase/projectList?(currentPage=${i})}">[[${i+1}]]</a>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work normally.
I'd appreciate your advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "_it doesn't work normally_"? What generated HTML do you expect to see, and what HTML do you actually get? You can [edit] the question to show us.

Comment: The only obvious problem I can see is that your Thymeleaf template should not include those two `?` characters, because Thymeleaf will automatically add those.